# Delay inside for loop not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I want to make a delay inside my `for` loop, but it won't really work.
 I've already tried my ways that are on stackoverflow, but just none of them work for what I want.

This is what I've got right now:

```
var iframeTimeout;
var _length = $scope.iframes.src.length;
for (var i = 0; i < _length; i++) {

    // create a closure to preserve the value of "i"
    (function (i) {
        $scope.iframeVideo = false;
        $scope.iframes.current = $scope.iframes.src[i];
        $timeout(function () {
            if ((i + 1) == $scope.iframes.src.length) {
                $interval.cancel(iframeInterval);
                /*Change to the right animation class*/
                $rootScope.classess = {
                    pageClass: 'nextSlide'
                }
                currentId++;
                /*More information about resetLoop at the function itself*/
                resetLoop();
            } else {
                i++;
                $scope.iframes.current = $scope.iframes.src[i];
            }
        }, $scope.iframes.durationValue[i]);

    }(i));

}
alert("done");
```

This is what I want:
First of all I got an object that holds `src`, `duration` and `durationValue`.
I want to play both video's that I have in my object.

1. I check how many video's I've got
2. I make `iframeVideo` visible (`ngHide`)
3. I insert the right `<iframe>` tag into my div container
4. It starts the `$timeout` with the right duration value
5. If that's done, do the same if there is another video. When it was the last video it should fire some code.

I hope it's all clear.

---

I've also tried this:

```
var iframeInterval;
var i = 0;

$scope.iframeVideo = false;
$scope.iframes.current = $scope.iframes.src[i];

iframeInterval = $interval(function () {
    if ((i + 1) == $scope.iframes.src.length) {
        $interval.cancel(iframeInterval);
        /*Change to the right animation class*/
        $rootScope.classess = {
            pageClass: 'nextSlide'
        }
        currentId++;
        /*More information about resetLoop at the function itself*/
        resetLoop();
    } else {
        i++;
        $scope.iframes.current = $scope.iframes.src[i];
    }
}, $scope.iframes.durationValue[i])
```

Comment: what are the values of `$scope.iframes.durationValue[i]` because that is the delay used...

Comment: Intergers like `10000` and `171000` for example.

Comment: Loops can't be delayed, you have to learn, how JS [timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers) work.

Comment: @Teemu but if you take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iiJDtnRm36LLztZh6RAw?p=preview) it just works.

Comment: `$timeout` returns promise. You can built a recursive chain of promises like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/WFSUwab4VmaxfFPf1r3D) so every next video will play after a small amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `$timeout` returns a different promise. To properly cancel them, you need to save everyone of them.

This example schedules several subsequent actions starting at time zero.

```
  var vm = $scope;
  vm.playList = []
  vm.playList.push({name:"video1", duration:1200});
  vm.playList.push({name:"video2", duration:1300});
  vm.playList.push({name:"video3", duration:1400});
  vm.playList.push({name:"video4", duration:1500});

  vm.watchingList=[];

  var timeoutPromiseList = [];
  vm.isPlaying = false;

  vm.start = function() {
      console.log("start");
      //ignore if already playing
      if (vm.isPlaying) return;
      //otherwise
      vm.isPlaying = true;
      var time = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < vm.playList.length; i++) {
        //IIFE closure
        (function (i,time) {
          console.log(time);
          var item = vm.playList[i];
          var p = $timeout(function(){playItem(item)}, time);
          //push each promise to list
          timeoutPromiseList.push(p);
        })(i,time);
        time += vm.playList[i].duration;
      }
      console.log(time);
      var lastPromise = $timeout(function(){vm.stop()}, time);
      //push last promise
      timeoutPromiseList.push(lastPromise);
  };
```

Then to stop, cancel all of the `$timeout` promises.

```
  vm.stop = function() {
      console.log("stop");
      for (i=0; i<timeoutPromiseList.length; i++) {
          $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromiseList[i]);
      }
      timeoutPromiseList = [];
      vm.isPlaying = false;
  };
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKBuAwcFYS8ymRUc4IZ4?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

`$timeout` returns promise. You can built a recursive chain of promises like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/WFSUwab4VmaxfFPf1r3D), so every next video will play after a small amount of time.